# Jquery Accordian into 2 column

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have used JQuery accordion in my JSP

```
<div id="accordion" class="subForms">
    <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.component"/></h3>
      <div></div>
      <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.sharedComponents"/></h3>
      <div></div>
       <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.testSystem"/></h3>
       <div></div>
       <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.incidents"/></h3>
       <div></div>
       <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.scm"/></h3>
       <div></div>
       <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.people"/></h3>
       <div></div>
       <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.skills"/></h3>
       <div></div>
</div>
```

And JS code is

```
var icons = {
                  header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
                  activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
                };
                $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                    icons: icons
                });
```

It gets output like this
[image]

I want this to align in two columns. That is first 4 to be aligned in left side, remaining to be in right side.

**(Components and SCM should be in same row)**

Is this possible? Or do I have to add two divs separately and setting accordion for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to add 2 Accordions for this, maybe try this:

```
<div id="accordion" class="subForms">
    <div class="leftCol">
    <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.component"/></h3>
      <div></div>
      <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.sharedComponents"/></h3>
      <div></div>
       <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.testSystem"/></h3>
       <div></div>
       <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.incidents"/></h3>
       <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightCol">
       <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.scm"/></h3>
       <div></div>
       <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.people"/></h3>
       <div></div>
       <h3><fmt:message key="dimApplicationForm.skills"/></h3>
       <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

var icons = {
                  header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
                  activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
                };
                $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                    icons: icons,
                    header: "h3"
                });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Lw34/3/

Comment: Thanks. But the jsfiddle link provided is other example. Might be copy problem :)